# Dual fire and positioning problems

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a space shooter and have this problem:

My space ship fires bullets. The bullets are centered in reference to the ship. Currently all bullets are single shots.

Now what I'd like to have is dual fire for the ship. Basically that means I have to double the shots and place them at the left and right
side of the ship, right? But I don't know how to do it exactly.

The other problem I have is that when I change the x and y-coordinates of the bullet in order to move the bullets from the center of the ship to the left (or right) and rotate the ship and fire I get a strange behavior of the bullets. In this case they move from the left to the center and vice versa referring to the ship (while rotating and firing).

Please - has anyone any idea where the problems might be and how to do it? I appreciate very much any help. TIA!:)

```
private function autoShoot(step:Number):void {  

    projectileManager.projectilePoolCount = projectileManager.projectilePool.length - 1;
    asteroidManager.asteroidCount = asteroidManager.asteroids.length;

        if (projectileManager.lastProjectileShot > projectileOffset && projectileManager.projectilePoolCount > 0 &&
        playerStarted && asteroidManager.asteroidCount > 0 && projNumber < projectileNumber)
    {

    dispatchEvent(new CustomEventSound(CustomEventSound.PLAY_SOUND, Main.SOUND_PLAYER_SHOOT,
            false, 0, 8, 1));
    tempProjectile = projectileManager.projectilePool.pop();
    tempProjectile.projectileDelayCount = 0;

    var projectileRadians:Number = (player.frame / 360) * 6.28;

    projShots++;
    projNumber++;

    if (projNumber >= projectileNumber)
    {
        player.startDelay = true;
    }   

    tempProjectile.x = (player.point.x) + Math.cos(projectileRadians);
    tempProjectile.y = (player.point.y) + Math.sin(projectileRadians);

    tempProjectile.x = player.x + 13;
    tempProjectile.y = player.y + 13;

    tempProjectile.nextX = tempProjectile.x;
    tempProjectile.nextY = tempProjectile.y;

    tempProjectile.dx = rotationVectorList[player.frame].x;
    tempProjectile.dy = rotationVectorList[player.frame].y;

    tempProjectile.speed = projectileSpeed;
    tempProjectile.frame = 0;

    tempProjectile.bitmapData = tempProjectile.animationList[0];

    tempProjectile.projectileDelay = 10;

    projectileManager.projectiles.push(tempProjectile);
    projectileManager.lastProjectileShot = 0;   

    } else {


    projectileManager.lastProjectileShot += step;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should make a bullet class. So all you need is to instantiate a bullet every time you need one. It would control starting point, ending point, speed, friction( if any )and trajectory. That should simplify everything for you

Comment: I already have a bullet class. But currently it's working for single shots only. Not dual fire.

Comment: Thats my point a dual shot is just 2 bullets. so when you have a 2 bullet weapon it will instantiate 2 bullet class objects. or make 2 types of bullet classes a single shot and a dual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autoShoot` function only fires one projectile each time it is called. There is only one `tempProjectile` per call to push to the `projectiles` list.

So one fix can be to add a `tempProjectile2` (in the same place `tempProjectile` is defined) as a variable that can be used. Now in each call the projectile pool gets depleted by two, as long an adequate number of projectiles are popped

```
tempProjectile = projectileManager.projectilePool.pop();
tempProjectile2 = projectileManager.projectilePool.pop();
```

then adjust the offset accordingly

```
tempProjectile.x
tempProjectile.y 
tempProjectile2.x
tempProjectile2.y
```

And so on with the rest of the code. The only thing I am unclear about is why tempProjectile.x and y are assigned twice.

```
tempProjectile.x = (player.point.x) + Math.cos(projectileRadians);
tempProjectile.y = (player.point.y) + Math.sin(projectileRadians);

tempProjectile.x = player.x + 13;
tempProjectile.y = player.y + 13;
```

only the second pair will be used, I think.

Hopefully the rest of the functions should not change because at the end the projectiles are pushed to the `projectiles` list

```
 projectileManager.projectiles.push(tempProjectile);
 projectileManager.projectiles.push(tempProjectile2);
```

So the whatever function used to update and render should remain the same, assuming tempProjectile is not tied down elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Thank you very much!:) I will try this asap. I hope it will work now.